# jQuery slow fade element on interval and fade back in if user hovers

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to show some notifications to the user which will appear on screen using the jQuery append method. Once they appear on screen I want to wait say 5 seconds and THEN slowly begin to fade the element out before removing it from the DOM. It should only begin its fade after 5 seconds and not start fading straight away. If a user hovers the element then it should fade the element back in and then when the user removes hover then it should begin fading out again.

I have this so far:

```
        setTimeout(function()
            {
                $(".Notification").fadeOut("slow", function ()
                {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

            }, 5000);
```

So this fades out the element after the time out but how do I make it so when a user hovers the element it fades back in. When the user removes hover it will begin fading out again (note: we don't need to wait anymore just reverse the fade everytime they hover the element unless it gets to the end of its fade and is removed)

Can anyone help? I presume it's just a simple case of wrapping the fadeOut part with some additional code but I'm struggling and would appreciate some help.

Also their could be multiple notifications appearing on the page so they all need to fade out based on their own appearance on screen and not fade them all out at the same time.

Effectively this is mimicking the new mail box you see in the bottom right of your screen when using Microsoft Outlook.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need a setTimeout. jQuery has got a .delay() function for animations.

```
/* Initial delay and fading out for 5s */
$(".Notification").delay(5000).fadeOut(5000);

/* If hover, stop the ongoing (or delayed) fadeout, and fadein fast */
$(".Notification").mouseenter(function(){

    $(this).stop(true, false).fadeIn(500);
});

/* If mouseout, set the element to fadeout slowly after 5s */
$(".Notification").mouseleave(function(){

    $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut(5000);
});
```

I haven't tried this actual example, but something like this should do it.

Comment: When I mouseover it doesn't fade the element back in?

Comment: In case you need to show it again on hover AFTER the entire fadeout. You need to animate the opacity instead of using .fadeOut(), such as `.animate({ opacity: 0}, 5000)` and `.animate({ opacity: 1}, 5000)`

Comment: No I wouldn't need to do that as it will be removed from the DOM after it has faded out! But when I hover it doesn't STOP the notification from fading out... how come? Cheers

Comment: Strange, I ran the example just now and it worked fine. Are you inserting the element with js? In that case you need to either change the `.mouseleave(function(){` to `.live("mouseleave", function(){` etc, or apply the code in the example after the new element is appended to the DOM.

Comment: What you're doing in the example is to fade out the `body` element, not the `.Notification` element.
This should do it [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9NcaD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

assign your setTimeout to a variable. Call clearTimeout on this variable when the user hovers over it.

Comment: Hi I wouldn't want to clear the Timeout as that's **ONLY** used to delay the initial fade. What I want to do is stop the fadeout when a user hovers the element and then when they remove hover the start fading out again.

Comment: so you can set the timeout again when they hover off, no?